# Insert in query string only the values of the selected checkboxes with their respective quantities inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having a problem here in mounting a query string with the variables that I need.
I have the following part of the code:

```
echo "<form class='additionals'>";               
foreach($connection->query($sql2) as $additional)
{
    echo "
    <input class='additional-checkbox' type='checkbox' name='additional_id' value='{$additional['additional_id']}'/>{$additional['additional_name']} - &#36;{$additional['additional_price']} <input type='number' name='additional_quantity' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
    ";
}
echo "</form>";
```

In this code snippet I get the values from database and insert each of them into a checkbox.
To get the values of the selected checkboxes I'm using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.add').on('submit', function()
    {
        var product_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-id').text();
        var product_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-name').text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input.additional-checkbox').is(':checked'))
        {
            var additionals = $(this).closest('tr').find( '.additionals' ).serialize();
            window.location.href = "add_to_cart.php?product_id=" + product_id + "&product_name=" + product_name + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&" + additionals;
        }
        else
        {
            window.location.href = "add_to_cart.php?product_id=" + product_id + "&product_name=" + product_name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Let's assume that only the checkbox with value `1` is selected and the input in front related to their quantity value is `3`. My output should be something like:
`add_to_cart.php?product_id=4&product_name=Pizza&quantity=1&additional_id=1&additional_quantity=3`
Here is my little problem. I have part of the output as I want, but the values of the other quantity inputs are also inserted to serialize. By this way the output is like:
`add_to_cart.php?product_id=4&product_name=Pizza&quantity=1&additional_id=1&additional_quantity=3&additional_quantity=1&additional_quantity=1`
How to make only the quantity of inputs relating to the selected checkboxes appear in the Query String? How to relate the inputs of checkboxes with the quantity inputs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
var additionals = $(this).closest('tr').find('.additionals')
```

returns multiple forms. Is it possible, that in single `TR` you have more than one such form?

Comment: No, I have one form for each group of additionals. I need to retrieve the values of only the selected checkboxes with their quantities in this form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input name="quantity_id" type="checkbox" data-quantity-input="quantity">
<input name="quantity" type="input" value="">

// get the data-quantity-input
var qtyInput = $(this).data('quantity-input');

// find the corresponding value if checkbox is checked
find('input[name='"+ qtyInput +'"]').val();
```

"data" attribute should be unique. You can use the index inside "for" loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm analyzing your code but do not know how to implement it on my system.

Comment: append "additional_id" to data-quantity-input="qty-{id}". This will be always unique corresponding to checkbox. If checkbox is checked, take this value of corresponding input based on "data" attribute value.

Comment: I got the problem. You are using serialize() function. Before calling this function, you should disabled input fields corresponding to check boxes which are not checked. Use $('.additional-checkbox').each() function.

Comment: Exactly, and that's what I'm trying to do for a long time. For this reason I said in the question "How to relate the inputs of checkboxes with the quantity inputs?" If the input is disabled I will not have their value to serialize. The problem is to disable the quantity input of their checkbox if this isn't checked, but I don't know how to relate both inputs.

Comment: Assign id={quantity_I'd} to input field and add the same id in data attribute to checkbox. Loop through all the checkbox using $.each, if not checked, disable the input having id specified in data attribute.

Comment: This may appear inside the of `$(document).ready(function()`? I think disable the quantity inputs if the checkbox is not selected is enough. Then I can serialize smoothly. I think I should use this in a click function for each checkbox with their input. Can you give me a code example? I'm not so familiar with JavaScript but I need it to parse all of these variables to PHP.